# How can I detect if an android device indoor with Google Fit?

Tags: android, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

We have an Android App which using Google Fit. We counting steps and distance for awarding users by this values.

But we want detect if device indoor. Is it possible with Google Fit Api?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't believe this is possible.  How would you expect it to be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

This feature does not exist in the Fit API yet. Looking through the docs, it does not mention a way to detect whether you are indoor or outdoor.